# Getting point based score using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

There is a table like follow:

```
Player    Weight    Hight    Agility
____________________________________
ABC        135       70         4
XYZ        155       65         1
PQR        121       69         7
MNO        171       73         5
```

I need a "Player Score" for each player, which is simply one point for each satisfied condition.

**Example Conditions:**
Weight < 150
Height > 67
Weight / Height < 1.8
Agility > 4

Thus based on above, the result might be:

```
Player     Score
________________
ABC          2
XYZ          0
PQR          4
MNO          2
```

Is it possible to achieve above using MYSQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up [MySQL flow control](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) and try something like this...

```
select player, (CASE when Weight < 150 then 1 else 0) + 
               (CASE when Height >  67 then 1 else 0) +
               (CASE when weight <  1.8*height then 1 else 0) +
               (CASE when Agility > 4  then 1 else 0) 
from table
```